# What is the uniform type identifier for ePub files?

Tags: ios, epub, uti

What is the UTI for .epub files?

Read the [Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) and can't find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The “Uniform Type Identifiers” framework defines constants for system defined types, such as [`epub`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551491-epub):

> A type that represents EPUB format data.
> The identifier for this type is `org.idpf.epub-container`.

One can obtain the type identifier at runtime with

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

print(UTType.epub)
// org.idpf.epub-container
```

Another way is to inspect the Info.plist from an application which can open EPUB files, such as the Books application:

```
...
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>org.idpf.epub-container</string>
</array>
...
```

Comment: The updated docs for it can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551491-epub)

Comment: @N.Jones: Thank you for the reference.